# Issue with the clear(); statement placement within ListViewAdpater

Tags: android, android-listview

So I was having problems with duplicate items showing up in the listview when switching between fragments using a drop down menu in the action, I placed a clear(); statement that fixed the problem, but crashes the convertView.setOnClickListener below it. If I remove the clear(); statement then everything works fine but I get the duplicate items in the listview. I am using ActionBarSherlock and this code was taken from http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-search-collapsible-view-in-android/ 
Any help would be greatly appriciated in trying to figure out how everything can work together. If there is any other code you need, let me know.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
// Declare Variables
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<ErrorCode> errorcodelist = null;
private ArrayList<ErrorCode> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<ErrorCode> errorcodelist) 
{
    mContext = context;
    this.errorcodelist = errorcodelist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ErrorCode>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(errorcodelist);
}

public class ViewHolder 
{
    TextView errorName;
    TextView codeValue;
    TextView description;
    TextView solution;
}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return errorcodelist.size();
}

@Override
public ErrorCode getItem(int position) 
{
    return errorcodelist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
} 

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.errorName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.errorName);
        holder.codeValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.codeValue);
        holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.solution = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.solution);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else 
    {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.errorName.setText(errorcodelist.get(position).getErrorName());
    holder.codeValue.setText(errorcodelist.get(position).getCodeValue());
    holder.description.setText(errorcodelist.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.solution.setText(errorcodelist.get(position).getSolution());
    errorcodelist.clear();

    // Listen for ListView Item Click
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SingleItemView.class);
            // Pass all data errorName
            intent.putExtra("errorName",(errorcodelist.get(position).getErrorName()));
            // Pass all data errorCode
            intent.putExtra("codeValue",(errorcodelist.get(position).getCodeValue()));
            // Pass all data description
            intent.putExtra("description",(errorcodelist.get(position).getDescription()));
            // Pass all data solution
            intent.putExtra("solution",(errorcodelist.get(position).getSolution()));
            // Start SingleItemView Class
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    return convertView;
}

// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) 
{
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    errorcodelist.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) 
    {
        errorcodelist.addAll(arraylist);
    }
    else
    {
        for (ErrorCode ec : arraylist)
        {
            // Search filter code
            if (ec.getErrorName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
            {
                errorcodelist.add(ec);
            }
            if (ec.getCodeValue().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
            {
                errorcodelist.add(ec);
            }
        }

    }       
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Here is the logcat when the convertView.setOnClickListener crashes:

```
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at com.testapplication.test2v5.ListViewAdapter$1.onClick(ListViewAdapter.java:93)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-07 15:09:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(21500):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you clear your List errorcodelist.get(position) will throw an Exception

Comment: When will the listview item gets duplicated? When you click or select a list?

Comment: apologies I forgot to put when I switch between fragments using a drop down menu is when I get the duplicates. It will keep adding the same listview item every time I switch. I have edited my statement.

Comment: Show the code of yout fragment. Maybe the problem is there. Did you try to call the notifyDataSetChanged in the fragment onResume method?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter the list being iterated by the adapter inside the own adapter methods, because you are changing the positions. Worst is to clear that list. This explains the new error. So, remove the clear() inside the getView method.

The duplicated items probably are comming from your filter, because it can add one item twice if it matches error and code. Change to:

```
         // Search filter code
        if (ec.getErrorName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
        {
            errorcodelist.add(ec);
        }
        else if (ec.getCodeValue().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
        {
            errorcodelist.add(ec);
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to state that the issue happens when switching between fragments using a drop down menu in the action bar. That code is for the search function I am also implementing, but it's working fine.

Comment: So, try calling notifyDataSetChanged(); on the onResume method of your fragment.